# Neovim don't copy/yang clipboard and primarboard in ›any‹ register

Tags: neovim

yesterday I chancend from vim to Neovim. Having already solved a few problems, and being so far content, there is one issue left.

I often copy via Clipboard Informations into my Vim-Wiki, in vim I used following mapping:

:nnoremap "+p  (enables to use in vim only p to put the clipboard-content to the vim-file)

in Neovim I can't find the content of the clipboard or primarboard(linux) in any register using:

:reg
:reg "+
:reg "*

or trying to put via:

p
"+ p
"* p

What is going on there?

best wishes tasmo

Answer (score 2):

... via

:h 'clipboard'

I find out quite like it works. Nvim needs to now witch tool the representive OS using.

And with

:checkhealth

I came to know, that Nvim can't find any.

So do I.

How can I find out the clipboardtool on my Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia, witch clipboardtool it uses?

And how do I tell this Neovim?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

... there was no clipboardtool like xclip or xsel installed.

On debian-systems it is easy to install with:

> $ sudo apt-get install xclip

Answer (score 0):

for me installing xclip using `sudo apt-get install xclip` worked.

Comment: Please do notice that "for me [...] worked" is not always the answer to the question. I would rather add that as a comment to the actual post.